# Java library for reading apk file (for building play store like app)

Tags: android, apk, java

My requirement is to develop an Play store like application. Where, developers will be uploading their Android .apk file.

Checking on the mobile application side can be done only with applications package path. Which requires the package path to be taken manually or by reading the .apk file of the application using library.

a) Making developer to enter application package path is not best of practice,
b) I searched online and found not any way to read the .apk file.

I am not sure if my approach is correct, please correct me if I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

There is an api/toolkit [android-apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/). 
for reading the .apk and xml meta-data

That should help

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply TechExchange, am I following the correct approach for developing the application? How to use this as a Java library?